# JQuery Validation plugin - dropdowns in webkit browsers do not show validation changes until blur

Tags: validation, webkit, jquery-validate, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown that has the first option with an empty string value and text theat says "Please select an option". I am using the Jquery validation plugin 1.7 (from bassistance.de) and would like this to be invalid until the user selects one of the other options that has a value.

After an attempted submit my invalid inputs are lit up correctly. In IE 8 and Firefox 3.6, when I select a valid value from my dropdown list the validation message goes away as soon as I select a valid value. It reappears if I select the "Please select an option" item as expected. However, in Safari and Chrome (Webkit browsers) the validation message does not appear/disappear until the dropdown loses focus.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this, which I was trying to avoid - it works but I wish the plugin gave me the option.

```
$('#state').change(function () {
    $('#contact-form').validate().element('#state');
});
```